# Detect firebase child value is "null" or "0"

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is the value in inside my firebaseDatabse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jimif.png)

[This is how I retrieve user infomation (e.g Name & Age)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBHop.png)

My questions is how to I check if the child value is "null"? 
Help and guidance needed...... 
Thanks

Comment: `null` or "null"? Firebase doesn't store null references so if the child exists it is non-null.

Comment: Please paste code, not screenshots

Comment: Firebase definitely stores null. It doesn't support undefined. There's a difference.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are a few methods you can call from a `DataSnapshot` to check if a value is 'null'.

The first thing is to make clear is that Firebase will not store a node or field with a null value, so something like `age: null` won't be in your database. If the value is null, the age field just won't be there at all.

So the methods available on a DataSnapshot are: `exists()`, `hasChild(String s)` and `hasChildren()` which can be used to check for the existence of something depending on what you're looking for.

Examples of usage would look like:

```
if (dataSnapshot.exists())

if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("age"))

if (dataSnapshot.child("name").exists())
```

If you want to check if the value is actually '0' as also mentioned in your question then there is nothing special to that; you would just check if the value equals zero the same as you would in any other situation.

Answer (score 2):

your getters will return a null for empty fields in your snapshot

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
if (dataSnapshot.exists()){}  OR
if (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() != 0){} OR
if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("childName")){}
```

**If there is no data, the snapshot will return false when you call
 exists() and null when you call getValue() on it.**